# Asp .net dropdownlist SelectedItem doesn't change after clear in dropdownlist

Tags: c#, asp.net, jquery-select2

I'm using the asp: DropDownList component with jquery Select2. It works but I expect to change the DropDownList SelectedItem property when I clear the item in DropDownList. As I understand, when I clear the item it is changing but again back to the previous state because of PostBack.

In Aspx file looks like this;

```
 <asp:DropDownList
       ID="countriesDdl"
       AutoPostBack="true"
       runat="server"
       class="js-example-placeholder-single" Width="200">
 </asp:DropDownList>
```

The scripts for the Select2();

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#<%=countriesDdl.ClientID%>").select2();
        $(".js-example-placeholder-single").select2({
            placeholder: "Select a code",
            allowClear: true,
            selectOnClose: false
        });
    });
</script>
```

Page_Init();

```
        countriesDdl.DataSource = countries;
        countriesDdl.DataTextField = "TEST";
        countriesDdl.DataValueField = "TESTID";
        countriesDdl.DataBind();
```

Comment: Are you initializing the DropDowList in server side? If so, Is this initialization in a !IsPostback?

Comment: And... do you have a "empty" value in the server side datasource?. I think the DropDownList can't set the value to empty if you don't have this value in the control items.
Also, it seems you are calling select2 twice. One by the DDL id and anothe by css class. I don't think this could be an issue, anyway. Most of jquery plugins allow multiple calls without side effects.

Comment: Yes, it's initialized on the server-side. And Initialization in the !IsPostback if condition. I don't have any empty values in the data source, all of them are filled key-value pairs. I think too, but I don't have any solution for that. Just a feeling :) 
So, you are right. I changed into the one select2() initialization but still, it is doesn't work. Many thanks!

Comment: Let me ask, so I understand it correctly: The DDL works as expected when a country is selected, but is not working when you select empty? In this case, you may need to add, after the .Databind(), something like this: countriesDdl.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("Select a code", ""));

Comment: Hey, thank you! I did it. It hasn't worked after I add "countriesDdl.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("Select a code", ""));" line after the BindData(). But, after I add the same Id to the Select2() initializer with the placeholder object it works!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got a solution. It may be a workaround solution but works for me;
I added static data In the Page_Init() function after DropDownList.DataBind() call.
The static data;

```
countriesDdl.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem { Text = "Select a code", Value = "0" });
```

But it wasn't enough. When initializing the Select2 component we must determine the id for a placeholder that of the must same with at the above LisItem.Value property value.
Such as this;

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#<%=countriesDdl.ClientID%>").select2({
                placeholder: {
                    id: 0,
                    text: "Select a code"
                },
                allowClear: true
            });
        });
 </script>
```